# Beginner question for javascript button behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running one of the front-end library projects for freeCodeCamp.com, and while I'm loving the program so far, I'm having a spot of trouble when it comes to jQuery.

My project can be found on this codepen:
https://codepen.io/UniqueUserName/pen/NWPKjJQ

here is the html:

```
<body>
<wrapper id="quote-box">
  <p id="text">

  </p>
    <p id="author">
    </p>
    <div id="twitter">
      <a href="twitter.com/intent/tweet" id="tweet-quote" title="tweet this quote!"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>     
        <button id="new-quote" class="btn btn-default">New Quote</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</wrapper>
</body
```

Here is the javascript:

```
let quotes = [
  "I'm searching for phrases, to sing your praises.",
  "If I could only turn back the clock to when God and her were born",
  "When I was in Missouri, they would not let me be",
]

function generateQuote() {
  let num = quotes.length - 1;
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
    return quotes[randomNumber];
};



$('#text').text(generateQuote);
$('#new-quote').on('click', generateQuote());
```

My issue is with the "new quote" button - it should generate a new quote from a small array of quotes - this works on reload, but I can't manage to get the button onclick to generate a new quote. If anyone with more experience than me could hop in and take a look, I'd surely be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function generateQuote() {
  let num = quotes.length;
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
  $("#text").text(quotes[randomNumber]);
};

generateQuote();
$("#new-quote").click(generateQuote);
```

Note that:

- `Math.random()` never returns 1
- instead of returning your quote from `generateQuote()`, you need to call `$("#text").text()`.